# how to receive data blocks from xlsm vba to google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an excel sheet with more than 5 thousand records and columns. I want to take all this data to a Google Sheets on a daily basis.

My question or problem is:
How are data blocks received in app scripts?
What is the syntax that should be placed as parameters?
In vba excel you can assign a data range to an arrays variable, but I don't know how to receive it in scripts.

I have tried going record by record but it is a slow process because it must access Google Drive as many times as there are records.

It occurs to me to carry in blocks or packages or Arrays. That way I could carry maybe 50 or 100 or maybe more records in a single variable, which would significantly reduce access to Google Drive.
I need to pass the data in blocks or arrays to reduce the number of accesses to Google Drive

Comment: Hi Josue Miguel thank for email me your concern. I don't have environment ready for Visual Basic Applications to reproduce your use case also don’t have ready google-apps-script. What I can suggest in google drive api there should be some settings to accept block data. Try find that settings.

Comment: Sahab, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y atención. Seguiré buscando una posible solución.